# A bald guy cuts his hand off instead of a chain to make an other guy fall into the void

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking movie from the 70's may be early 80's. Their clothes and the atmosphere of the scene make me think that it is a science fiction movie, but I am not sure.

I remember a scene from the end:

Two guys on a platform. A bald guy, the good one, and a bad guy.

The bad guy hangs in the void, held by a chain attached to his wrist. The other end of the chain is attached to the wrist of the good guy. He is on the platform.

The good guy tries to cut the chain with an axe. He does not succeed and finally resolves to cut his own hand off and the bad guy falls into the void, in a certain death.

The decor is minimalist. It is the interior of a futuristic urban building.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [*The Ultimate Warrior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ultimate_Warrior_(film)) released in 1975, starring Yul Brynner (the bald guy).

Set in a post apocalyptic New York, it depicts the struggles of a small enclave of inhabitants attempting to survive in a compound beset with packs of starving pillagers.

You can watch the relevant scene here:

Comment: _"Carson kills Carrot"_ -> I don't think I like the sound of this film.

Comment: this is exacly what i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: ...stay next to the damn pillars! Pick up dirt and throw it in his face....